# Laravel CSS asset function doesn't point to correct URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel, in my layout blade template file (used by all my views) I have the following code to generate my stylesheet URL:

`<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

When the page is generated this appears like this: `http://myapp.test/css/app.css` which looks like its correct, I have a file in the following directory `\resources\css\app.css`.

When I try and access the css file directly via the URL, laravel throws a 404 error, can someoen tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using `mix.css` or `mix.sass` or anything similar, but creating it using `mix`, then use [`mix`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-mix) in blade aswell.

Comment: [`resources/`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/structure#the-resources-directory) is for raw, uncompiled JS/CSS.  Mix and webpack etc compile those and generate output in [`public/`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/structure#the-public-directory).  If you're not using webpack just put the files in `public/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `{{ asset('css/app.css') }}` , laravel points to `public/app.css`.

Browser can only access contents of inside public folder.

Laravel uses webpack which complies css file located inside `resources/css` and saves into `public/css`.

If you look inside `webpack.mix.js` located in root folder of your project you can see following:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')    
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    //
]);
```

So, if you access `http://myapp.test/css/app.css` , you should get css located in your public folder. you can confirm this from `source` tab of your browser's developer tools (i.e. page inspect).

Comment: You have a typo in the first sentence here - `asset('css/app.css')` points to `public/css/app.css`.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using mix.css or tailwind or anything, and are writing your own css, put it in `/public/css/app.css`

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer